# Put the value of a DIV inside a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code and I need to put the result of the translation inside a PHP variable to send it to a BD. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Translate API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
    <script>
      function translateText(response) {
        document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);

      var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=--MY API KEY --&source=en&target=fr&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
      newScript.src = source;

      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the time the javascript runs, the server is done with the call, so you would need to create a new request (maybe through ajax) that would send the data back to the server.

Comment: You need to use some ajax

Comment: I don't know anything about AJAX, can anyone help me?

Comment: Here's an introduction to AJAX: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp